# Get values of selected checkboxes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get an array of selected checkboxes once a submit button has been clicked in jQuery, I can't seem to get anything to show. Code below:

jQuery:

```
$(".btn").live("click",function () {
    var ffirst = $('input:checkbox[name="first[]"]:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
});
$.each(ffirst, function(index, value) {
    alert(index + ': ' + value);
});
```

And HTML below:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="first[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" checked="checked" name="first[]">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Go">
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: changed per comments, but still broken.

Comment: Which are you Jquery version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've used bad selector, use:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="first[]"]:checked')
```

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YfdXZ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your JS:

```
name=first
```

Your HTML:

```
name="first[]"
```

These do not match.

Add the square brackets. You also need to quote them since they are not alphanumeric.

```
$('input:checkbox[name="first[]"]:checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".btn").on("click",function () {
    $('input:checkbox[name="first[]"]:checked').each(function(index) {
        alert(index + ': ' + this);
        console.log(this);
        console.log($(this));
    });
});
```

Just use (.live) if really needed

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the ffirst array before the click handler as it's out of scope. The each loop will have to happen in the click handler as it will need to execute once the array has been populated.

Not the most optimised code but here's a working an example:

```
var ffirst = []; 
$(".btn").live("click",function () {
  ffirst = $('input[name="first[]"]:checked').map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
  });

  $.each(ffirst, function(index, value) {
    alert(index + ': ' + value);
  });
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BxsqN/)